# Leningrad, Triangle.

Tags: geometry

Angle bisectors AF, BG and CH in triangle ABC are drawn. It is known that Â = 120°. Find the angle GFH.

I tried to use the idea that
all points belonging to the bisector of an angle, equidist on the sides of that angle, but nothing so far.

Comment: Leningrad's relevance ?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 4):

90 degrees

Extend BA and find A' such that AC=AA'. ACA' is equilateral. CA'//FA. So BF/AF=BC/A'C=BC/AC=BH/AH. So HF bisects BFA.

Due to symmetry GF bisects CFA.

So GFH=AFB/2=90 degrees

Thanks @nickgard for pointing out a typo.

Comment: @qyu how you prove that CA'//FA?

Comment: @thiagodurso It's because CA'B=FAB=60 degrees.

Comment: @qyu okay! But I still don't understand why BC / AC = BH / AH. And why does that mean that HF ​​bisects BFA. Sorry for many questions.

Comment: At any vertex  an angle bisector divides opposite side in the ratio of its adjacent sides. The converse theorem states that if a line divides opposite sides in the same ratio of adjacent sides,$BC/AC=BH/AH$,  then that line is a bisector of angle at this  vertex C.

Comment: Now, I can only understand why BC/AC=BH/AH. Is it about similarity of triangles?

Comment: @Narasimham, is it?

Comment: @thiagodurso Yes, it is. $CA'\parallel FA$ so $BFA$ and $BCA'$ are similar triangles, and hence $BF/AF=BC/A'C=BC/AC$

Answer (score 1):

At any vertex an angle bisector divides opposite side in the ratio of its adjacent sides. The converse theorem states that if a line divides opposite sides in the same ratio of adjacent sides,BC/AC=BH/AH, then that line is a bisector of angle at this vertex C.

To have segment parts of a triangle to have the same ratio, parallelism is ***not the only*** possibility. You may perhaps find it as a stumbling block in qyu's nice answer.

If you work out to find what the ratio of sides should be in order that the said ratio be constant, you would find another possibility in that the meeting vertex locus is an [***Apollonius Circle***,](https://images.search.yahoo.com/search/images;_ylt=AwrXoCAF1m9eDnsAPjnQtDMD;_ylu=X3oDMTE0Ym81cHVuBGNvbG8DZ3ExBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDQjk3NzlfMQRzZWMDcGl2cw--?p=Apollonius%20circle&fr2=piv-web&fr=mcafee#id=14&iurl=http%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fen%2F9%2F9d%2FApollonius_circle_definition_labels.png&action=click) whose references are found on the net.

Comment: How would it be?